# Performance question - what are the defects of high level programming languages and compilers that makes assembly still a better choice today

Tags: performance, assembly

What I want to know is, how can we still make use of assembly today, in productive manners?

When assembly outperform C, so it would seem practical to write a section of the project in assembly rather than C, even if this will be a section of C/C++ project. I am not talking about pure assembly project here

I also referring to any kind of softwares nowadays whether AI, Image processing, video games,etc. any field where assembly is needed today, beside writing microchips for embedded systems.

Note: please do not explain what is assembly, but rather how to make use of it in C/C++ projects in various fields, also i am recent graduate CS&AI. I also have background of AI, Video Games and computer graphics. if it's useful i'd be interested in using it in my projects.

Comment: Are you aware of SIMD intrinsics? Those cover a lot of the more optimized features of a processor where one might have used assembly in the past.

Comment: see [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Comment: @gnat I asked it because i cant find an answer some posts says assembly is useless nowadays. while others say it is but I cannot reach these people. this question asking for examples for specific cases which is when Assembly outperform C which is is not if you read this topic you shared it says there's no right answer! if a scenario where assembly outperform C then this is a right answer or a single answer. but in programming there's many way to solve a problem so your logic is invalid. a guy who claim to work for MS with high rep said i cannot perform a query but i managed to do it.

Comment: @Sirisian no i am not.

Comment: Read CACM queue [C is not a low level language](https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=3212479). In practice, people don't code a lot of assembler these days (because C compilers are optimizing quite well)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assembly is widely avoided. It is more difficult to write than high-level languages, and doesn't reward this difficulty with noticeably better performance. Yes, the very best assembly programmers might be able to write better assembly than an optimizing compiler, but that compiler is much better than the vast majority of programmers.

The difficulty of writing really fast assembly is that this requires a very detailed understanding of the processor family you are targeting. Not just on a level of “x86-64 architecture”, but on a level of “Skylake microarchitecture”. The cost of one assembly instruction also depends on which instructions are executed around it. Optimizing compilers have appropriate cost models for that and can make good use of processor pipelining.

This leaves two cases where writing assembly can be appropriate:

1. For extremely critical sections where you cannot rely on compiler optimizations.

   The argument here is not that the compiler isn't good enough, but that you don't want to risk future compiler versions emitting worse assembly. Another reason could be that you have information that you cannot make available to the compiler, e.g. that would allow you to elide bookkeeping that would be normally required by the calling convention.
2. To make use of instruction set features that are not available in your language.

   Instruction sets have many processor-specific extensions. Importantly, SIMD instructions allow you to vectorize your code, which can drastically improve data throughput for certain use cases like media transcoding, cryptography, or numerics. A compiler may not be able to use these extensions unless you explicitly enable them for the compiler, might not be aware of newer extensions, or may not be able to use them because they would violate the semantics of your language.

   Where an application relies on vectorization, it is however often better to use a dedicated coprocessor instead of a general-purpose CPU. GPUs are exactly such a coprocessor, and are therefore frequently used for graphics or ML (which is mostly just lots and lots of matrix multiplications that are easy to vectorize into fused-multiply-add instructions). Instead of using assembly, you may therefore see larger benefits from writing shaders or using technologies like OpenCL or CUDA.

Finally, writing assembly or using vectorization might not necessarily make your code run any faster. You still need to be aware of the microarchitecture. E.g. using SIMD instructions can even make your code run slower because multiple cores might share a vector unit, thus turning these instructions into a bottleneck.

As with any performance work, don't “optimize” blindly:

1. Determine actual performance requirements.
2. Measure the performance. Profile the software for bottlenecks.
3. Try out an optimization for these bottlenecks. Measure it. If it doesn't help, discard it.
4. Repeat until your performance requirements are met.

Optimizations are easier when the software is written in an easy to understand style. The biggest wins don't come from doing the same thing faster, but from finding ways to avoid unnecessary work. Writing assembly works counter to this goal because it makes the software significantly harder to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Even in embedded systems, assembly is rarely used today. It is really hard to hand-craft assembly code that outperforms the code that gets generated by modern optimizing compilers and that becomes worse when you target more modern processors.

In my experience, assembly is only used when you need more control over the instruction and/or register usage than what a compiler can give you. The prime examples here come from the field of operating systems where you might want to execute privileged instructions in the kernel that the compiler just can't emit or you need to mess with special registers like the program counter or stack pointer to implement task switching.